# Is there any ArrayList<String> collection in C++ like in Java?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am using native function in my java class.

I have written C++ function for XML parsing.

My problem is that after parsing XML, i have to store node names into string array, but i dont want to fix its size.

Like java, C++ have any collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for just this?

```
vector<string> var;
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28C%2B%2B%29

It's used pretty much the same way but with different method names.

Answer (score 1):

There's `std::vector<std::string>` provided by the STL.

[Here's the documentation for `std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)